# Visualization of fully-connected neural networks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to visualize a neural network built by `keras` with the following structure where all three `Dense` layers include a bias term.

[image: Network structure]

I found this tool to visualize neural networks: [NN SVG](http://alexlenail.me/NN-SVG/index.html). When I selected `Show Bias Units`, I got this result:

[image: NN SVG Visualization]

However, I think the following visualization should be the correct one since the plot created by `NN SVG` does not include the bias term of the first `Dense` layer. Currently I'm confused with the difference between the two visualization plots. Can someone knidly explain it to me?

[image: Googled Visualization]

Comment: It looks like NN SVG is assuming one of the units is the bias unit, which is not how Keras reports it. Add 1 to the size of each dense layer, when you run NN SVG.